# Eclipse and catkin problems (symbol could not be resolved)

Tags: catkin, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

unfortunately i ran into some problems when trying to debug my rospackage in Eclipse (Kepler).

I followed these instructions in terminal:

1. catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"   (in my catkin workspace)
2. source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
3. eclipse

Then importing the project to eclipse works also fine.

But editing one file in the [Source directory]/myPackage/src/talker.cpp result in these errors, for example for this line of code:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
```

i recieve these errors:

```
-symbol advertised could not be resolved
-Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: ros::Publisher advertise(const ? &, unsigned int, bool) ros::Publisher advertise(ros::AdvertiseOptions &) ros::Publisher advertise(const ? &, unsigned int, const boost::function<void (const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher &)> &, const boost::function<void (const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher &)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &, bool) ' talker.cpp  /Project-Debug@build/[Source directory]/rosgui/src  line 83 Semantic Error
```

also eclipse can't find: #include

this is what i tried so far:

- running `cmake ./src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`  (in my catkin_workspace)
- rebuilding the indexer in eclipse
- tried it with eclipse Indigo

here the include paths in eclipse properties:

```
#ROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1
#ROS_PACKAGE_NAME="rosgui"
/usr/src/gtest
/home/thomas/catkin_ws/devel/include
/home/thomas/catkin_ws/src/rosgui/include
/opt/ros/groovy/include
/usr/include
```

Thank your very much for any advice!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68074/eclipse-and-catkin-problems-(symbol-could-not-be-resolved)/) by [thomas3687](https://answers.ros.org/users/5482/thomas3687/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-01-28**:
Same problem:  http://answers.ros.org/question/105446/eclipse-ide-problem/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should include those paths:

/usr/include/c++/4.6

/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu

/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward

---

Originally posted by [barcelosandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4303/barcelosandre/) with karma: 168 on 2013-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-01-27**:
Did not work for me (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Eclipse Kepler, ROS Hydro)

**Comment by [gurou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18887/gurou/) on 2014-06-16**:
It works for me. (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Eclipse Kepler, ROS Hydro) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem. Here's the solution:

1. Open Preferences
2. Go to C/C++ -> Indexer
3. Uncheck "Allow heuristic resolution of includes" and click OK
4. Right-click on your project
5. Click Index -> Rebuild

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [renaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/7031/renaud/) with karma: 41 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-01-27**:
Did not work for me (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Eclipse Kepler, ROS Hydro)

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-06-03**:
It worked for me. (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Eclipse Kepler, ROS Hydro) Thanks!

**Comment by [gurou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18887/gurou/) on 2014-06-16**:
It works for me. (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Eclipse Kepler, ROS Hydro) Thanks!

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-11-24**:
Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo. Still have unresolved errors, on ROS_INFO for example.